# Set All side Margin to a custom Entry in Xamarin.Forms (ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, margin, renderer

I have a custom Entry element and want to give extra margin ios (like '5,5,5,5') by the TextPaddingForIOS attached property

I created an ios renderer which does its job

```
using CoreGraphics;    
using FrameWork.Common;    
using UIKit;    
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer( typeof( TheEntry ), typeof( MyAssembly.iOS.TheEntry_iOSRenderer ) )]

namespace MyAssembly.iOS;

public class TheEntry_iOSRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
  private TheEntry _theEntry;
  private UITextField _uiTextField;
  protected override void OnElementChanged( ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e )
  {
    base.OnElementChanged( e );
    if( this.Control == null )
    {
      return;
    }

    _uiTextField = this.Control;
    _theEntry = (TheEntry)e.NewElement;
    if( _theEntry == null )
    {
      return;
    }


    //Set extra padding for the Text of the Entry
    this.addExtraPaddingIfNeeded();

    _theEntry.TextChanged += this.theEntry_TextChanged;
    this.updateBorder();
    this.updateBackground();
  }


  private void theEntry_TextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
  {
    this.updateBackground();
  }

  private void updateBackground()
  {
    if( _theEntry.IsReadOnly || _theEntry.IsEnabled == false )
    {
      _uiTextField.BackgroundColor = _theEntry.BackgroundColorReadOnly != Color.Default
                                   ? _theEntry.BackgroundColorReadOnly.ToUIColor()
                                   : null;
      return;
    }

    if( _theEntry.BackgroundColorMandatory != Color.Default )
    {
      if( _theEntry.Text.IsEmpty() )
      {
        _uiTextField.BackgroundColor = _theEntry.BackgroundColorMandatory.ToUIColor();
        return;
      }
    }

    _uiTextField.BackgroundColor = _theEntry.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
  }

  private void updateBorder()
  {
    _uiTextField.BorderStyle = _theEntry.BorderWidth == 0
                             ? UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None
                             : UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
  }


  private void addExtraPaddingIfNeeded()
  {
    if( _theEntry.TextPaddingForIOS == new Thickness( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) ) { return; }

    var paddedTextField = new PaddedTextField()
    {
      Padding = new UIEdgeInsets(
        (float)_theEntry.TextPaddingForIOS.Top,
        (float)_theEntry.TextPaddingForIOS.Left,
        (float)_theEntry.TextPaddingForIOS.Bottom,
        (float)_theEntry.TextPaddingForIOS.Right ),
        AttributedText = Control.AttributedText,
        ClearButtonMode = Control.ClearButtonMode,
        Font = Control.Font,
        Delegate = Control.Delegate,
        Background = Control.Background,
        BackgroundColor = Control.BackgroundColor,
    };


    SetNativeControl( paddedTextField );

  }
}

public class PaddedTextField : UITextField
{
  public UIEdgeInsets Padding { get; set; }

  public override CGRect TextRect( CGRect forBounds )
  {
    return base.TextRect( forBounds ).Inset( Padding.Top, Padding.Left );
  }

  public override CGRect EditingRect( CGRect forBounds )
  {
    return base.EditingRect( forBounds ).Inset( Padding.Top, Padding.Left );
  }
}
```

and here is xaml code

```
 <TheEntry Grid.Row="5"
                     Margin="{x:OnPlatform Android='4,0,4,4', iOS='4,2,4,4'}"
                     Text="{Binding Signatory}"
                     TextColor="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"
                     BackgroundColorMandatory="#50FFF69B"
                     BackgroundColorReadOnly="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}"
                     TextPaddingForIOS="{x:OnPlatform iOS='5'}"
                     FontSize="{DynamicResource DataEntry_Font_Size}"
                     Placeholder="{loc:Translate 502761, Text='Enter the signers name.'}"
                     PlaceholderColor="{DynamicResource ForegroundErrorColor}"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextEditable}"
                     >
```

the only problem is here the theEntry_TextChanged event is not triggered anymore. But I remove calling this method addExtraPaddingIfNeeded, then it works.

I tried to use Control.LeftView and LeftViewMode, but could not achive.

Comment: Could you please post the code of `TheEntry`?